# Map a network drive to be used by a service

Tags: hard-drive, script, nas, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to map a network drive (the WD My Cloud HDD) to be used by a service (CrashPlan backup software) in Windows 8, something that I have achieved with this script:

```
net use X: \\WDMYCLOUD\MyShare /u:WORKGROUP\user password /persistent:yes
```

However, I need to keep the map after rebooting.

Following instructions from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182750/map-a-network-drive-to-be-used-by-a-service) I know I have to run a scrip from the SYSTEM user.

I have read about using a startup or logon script (as proposedin that solution), or using the scheduled tasks tool as [perfectly explained here](http://blog.davidwarburton.net/2010/03/12/using-crashplan-to-backup-a-network-share/).

However, the best I have achieved is to see the map, but when I try to enter the X:/ drive it says that the user or password is incorrect.

What is more surprising, if I access the network drive, using the same username and password used for the script, then I can access X:, the mapping starts working.

What is wrong? Could it be that the drive is mounted for the SYSTEM account but nor for my Windows Account?

Some of the questions:

- Should I use the startup/logon script or the scheduled tasks?
- What is the problem with my password?
- Should I use "WORKGROUP" or my computer's name as the domain? Or no domain is needed?
- What about SysinternalsSuite by Mark Russinovich, which is mentioned as a first step in stackoverflow? Is it really needed if I am going to reboout the computer?
- Is creating a process [as explaiend here](http://rahul-oncall.blogspot.com/2011/04/how-to-map-network-drive-to-be-used-by.html) a better solution?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

I have had problems with Windows network drives on start-up. The drive is permanent (I set it up through explorer / map network drive), but after a reboot shows its status as disconnected in explorer until it is actually opened.

I work round it with a start-up script containing `if not exist x:\*.* start /min explorer x:\`. Put this command into, for example, `DriveCheck.cmd`, and create a link in the "All Users" start-up folder to launch `cmd /c DriveCheck.cmd`, adding the appropriate directories.

Not a perfect solution, as there is still an instance of explorer to cancel at some point, but it gets over the immediate problem.

Comment: "Put this command into, for example, DriveCheck.cmd" - what does it mean?

Comment: Create a file called `DriveCheck.cmd` and copy that line into it. I can't see what else it could mean.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know the cmd file extension, sorry for that.
Why is it that you need to execute that command? What is the difference between "net use" command and the "map network drive" option in Windows?

Comment: I don't think there is one, but I thought I should mention that I set up my share differently. The command makes sure that the network share is accessed from explorer after a reboot before other programs try to use it. I have no idea why this is necessary, but I have found that it is.